# Reactjs: Components are not changing by clicking on NavLinks

Tags: reactjs, components, router

Basically, I am learning React Routing with `react-router-dom`, `version 5.0.0` and I have some components like Home, About, Contact etc. and I am trying to change each component by clicking on NavLink but not changing components just changing URL

Indexjs:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import './Style.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Web from "./Web";


ReactDOM.render(
    <React.Fragment>
        <Header />
        <Web />
        <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
    , document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.register();
```

Web Componet:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, NavLink, Redirect, Switch,withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
//import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route';
import {Home} from "./components/Home";
import {About} from "./components/About";
import {Contact} from "./components/Contact";
import {Products} from "./components/Products";

class Web extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={"/"} exact component={withRouter(Home)}/>
                    <Route path={"/products"} component={withRouter(Products)}/>
                    <Route path={"/about"} component={About}/>
                    <Route path={"/contact"} component={Contact}/>
                    <Route path={"/something"} render={
                        () => {
                            return (<h1>This is something page</h1>);
                        }
                    }/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default Web;
```

Header Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.jpg';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, NavLink, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Router>
                <header className={'header_area'}>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="logo">
                            <a href="/"><img src={logo} alt="logo"/></a>
                        </div>
                        <nav className={'main_nav'}>
                            <ul>
                                <li><NavLink to="/" activeStyle={{color:"green"}} exact>Home</NavLink></li>
                                <li><NavLink to="/products" activeStyle={{color:"green"}} exact>Products</NavLink></li>
                                <li><NavLink to="/about" activeStyle={{color:"green"}} exact>About</NavLink></li>
                                <li><NavLink to="/contact" activeStyle={{color:"green"}} exact>Contact</NavLink></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <div className="float_clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Home Component:

```
import React from 'react';

export class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <article className={'article_area'}>
                    <div className="container article">
                        <h2>Home</h2>

                    </div>
                </article>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

About Component:

```
import React from 'react';

export class About extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <article className={'article_area'}>
                    <div className="container article">
                        <h2>About us</h2>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: follow this docs ... https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: Components are not changing if click on Home or About just changing URL @RaiTalhaRehmanKhan

Comment: use single router you are using in multiple component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a single `Router` and all of your routes and links should have it as one of their parents.

Change your index:

```
<React.Fragment>
    <Router>
        <Header />
        <Web />
        <Footer />
    </Router>
</React.Fragment>
```

and remove other `<Router>`s

Also you do not need to use `withRouter` for components inside `Route`. They will get react-router props directly.